# Link SDL in archive file

Tags: c, .a

I've got a projects, for an embedded STM32.

I've got some code "strategy" used to determinate where the robot should be going. The strategy uses a "pathfinding" library.

The latter can use SDL for debugging (and it's cool :) ). It uses a USE_SDL flag to include (or not) the sdl source files and compile with(out) the SDL gcc flags.

For now I create a .a archive file, containing the pathfinding library, to be linked later with the strategy object files. It works fine without SDL.

I want the strategy project to be COMPLETELY independent from SDL, even in the makefile.
So i'd like to "link" the SDL libraries INSIDE the .a file, and then link it with the strategy files.

How can I link the SDL with the pathfinding library, without having to know it in the strategy files/makefile ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot link libraries to libraries. (Static) libraries (I conclude from the tag you choose we are talking about static libs) are just object file containers.

What you can do (although it's not really practical if these libs come from external sources and you expect updates) is to extract all the object files from both libraries and stuff them into a new one linking against that in future:

```
ar x lib1.a
ar x lib2.a
ar rv new_lib.a *.o
ranlib new_lib.a
```